# Merge two Cells into One with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel that I'm trying to make helper columns with for comparisons and searches made up of two cells in the same row. 
The Main Error I have with doing this is a Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.
The Second Error I know will be present is that Cell 3 is in string format and has Prefixed 0s. I was able to remove them with a formula by changing the Number Format to "Number" before concatenating but I'm unsure how to do that in a Macro.

I know if I was to do it manually in excel as a formula it would look like this: `=CONCAT(NUMBERVALUE(C#),D#)`

```
hrow = HSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For J = 2 To hrow
    HSheet.Range("F" & J) = Application.VLookup(HSheet.Range("D" & J), PP.Range("D2:L" & lastrow), 9, False)
    HSheet.Range("I" & J).Cell.Value = HSheet.Range("C" & J).Cell.Value & HSheet.Range("D" & J).Cell.Value
Next J
```

An Example of the data in my Cells in case it matters:

```
Cell C   |  Cell D  |    Cell I   |
 0032    | AB975050 |  32AB975050 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Range.Cell.Value` when you should just be using `Range.Value`

```
HSheet.Range("I" & J).Value = HSheet.Range("C" & J).Value & HSheet.Range("D" & J).Value
```

Comment: That fixed the first error of the run time error but like i mentioned is it possible to convert the first value into the Number format rather than string format (It has preceding 00s) I'm not sure of how to do it in vba unlike using a formula

Comment: A sneaky way to convert strings to numbers is to just add 0. So, range.value + 0 & Range.Value + 0

Comment: Many Thanks. I didn't know you could just add a 0 to it to convert it.